# How to intercept the event when all controls are completely bound to data?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I'm working on an MVC3 application which uses knockout.js as a client side js library. We have a complex screen with list-like controls and grids that are populated with data by javascript using knockout.js. My problem is that I don't know how could I intercept the event when all controls are completely bound, i.e. are ready to be used by the end user. Currently, the page loads in the browser in 7 seconds but it takes around 20-30 seconds for the controls to get bound to the data which makes the page unusable until everything is ready. Is there any way to know when all controls are completely bound ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 20-30 seconds? Sounds like you have serious performance problems with your KO code.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't have any asynchronous logic in your viewmodels or custom binders, then you can just put a line of code directly after `applyBindings`:

```
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);   
doSomethingElse();
```

Here is a fiddle with a long-running binder that demonstrates this (be sure to open the console to see the output): http://jsfiddle.net/tlarson/bPaCb/

However, if you do have asynchronous logic (such as calling a web service with ajax), then you'll need to use the callbacks to run code after everything is done.  Here is what I typically do is:

1. Set up my view model with a boolean observable indicating that data is not yet loaded: `self.isLoaded = ko.observable(false);`
2. Add a 'Waiting' indicator (spinner, etc.) that is visible when the observable is false: `<div data-bind=visible:!isLoaded()"><img src="spinner.gif"></img></div>`
3. Similarly, hide the views until `isLoaded` is true: `<div data-bind="visible:isLoaded">Data views go here</div>`
4. call `applyBindings(myViewModel);` to get all of the bindings set up.  This should not include any ajax calls yet - the data should be empty.
5. Make the ajax call to load data.  When the data comes back, update the appropriate data properties on your viewmodel, the set `isLoaded` to true.  This will hide the spinner and show your data.